# IPMI sdr entity 8 (memory module) only showing 3 records?

Tags: monitoring, dell-poweredge, debian-squeeze, ipmi, ipmitool

I've got two Dell PE R710's -

- A has a single socket and 3 DIMMs in one bank
- B has both sockets and 6 (2 banks @ 3 DIMMs) filled

The output from "ipmitool sdr entity 8" confuses me - according to the
OpenIPMI documentation these are supposed to represent DIMM slots.

Output from A (1 CPU, 3 DIMMS, 1 bank.):

```
~#: ipmitool sdr entity 8

Temp             | 0Ah | ok  |  8.1 | 27 degrees C
Temp             | 0Bh | ns  |  8.1 | Disabled
Temp             | 0Ch | ucr |  8.1 | 52 degrees C
```

Output from B (2 CPUs, 3 DIMMS in both banks, 6 total):

```
~#: ipmitool sdr entity 8

Temp             | 0Ah | ok  |  8.1 | 26 degrees C
Temp             | 0Bh | ok  |  8.1 | 25 degrees C
Temp             | 0Ch | ucr |  8.1 | 51 degrees C
```

Now, I'm starting to think this output isn't DIMMS themselves, but maybe a sensor for each bank and something else? (Otherwise, shouldn't I see 6 readings for the one with both banks active?)

The CPU's aren't near 50 deg C, so I doubt the significantly higher reading is due to proximity - Is anyone able to explain what I'm seeing?

Does the output from my `ipmitool sdr entity 8 -v` [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YKwXEHHC) seem to hint at different sensors?

The sensor naming conventions are poor - seems like a dell thing.

Here is output from [racadm racdump](http://pastebin.com/9gMVRhWR)

Answer (score 1):

at first i would suggest you doing a complete dump of the ipmi card (iDRAC6), you can do this by connecting to the management IP via SSH and issue:
racadm racdump

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/idrac/idrac10mono/en/ug/html/racugaa.htm#wp64511

By checking the debug output you should be able to correlate to which sensor this translates, but honestly to me it looks related to CPU readings.
If you can post me the racdump will try to look into this

Comment: racdump here: http://pastebin.com/9gMVRhWR

Comment: I'm not seeing any sensor data from the racdump

Comment: /admin1-> racadm getsensors
ERROR: Invalid subcommand specified.